# error: socket hang up when appium is running

Tags: websocket, automated-tests, appium, adb, nodes

I'm new in appium and in my simple automated test I face by a problem that I don't know why sometimes happen!
This is what happens in my appium log:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBemK.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM0Yh.png)

I just run appium and after that run my code and my virtual device can't link to appium.
what's your opinion? I searched but I can't find the main problem? (I'm working with Linux/appium version:v1.21.0)

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Did you check your desired caps?

Comment: yes, but everything was correct.